# Multiple Logical Operators in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to check the following

1: Is x a number
2. If x is less that 5 or greater than 15, sound alert
3. If all is ok, callMe()

```
var x = 10;
if (isNaN(x) && ((x < 5) || (x > 15))) {
alert('not allowed')
}
else
{
callMe();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

```
var x = 10;
if (isNaN(x) || (x < 5) || (x > 15)) {
    alert('not allowed')
}
else
{
    callMe();
}
```

This way, if x is not a number you go directly to the alert. If it is a number, you go to the next check (is x < 5), and so on.

Comment: Simple and correct. When `x` is not a number, the first condition is True and it won't check further comparison conditions.

Comment: @Naomi: To explain your code: Your condition was that `x` is not a number **and** it should be smaller than 5 or greater then 15. But how can **NaN** be smaller or bigger than a number?

Answer (score 2):

All the other answers about the && vs || are correct, I just wanted to add another thing:

The `isNaN()` function only checks whether the parameter is the constant `NaN` or not. It doesn't check whether the parameter is actually number or not. So:

```
isNaN(10) == false
isNaN('stackoverflow') == false
isNaN([1,2,3]) == false
isNaN({ 'prop' : 'value'}) == false
isNaN(NaN) == true
```

In other words, you cannot use it to check whether a given variable contains a number or not. To do that I'd suggest first running the variable through `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` depending on what values you expect there. After that check for `isNaN()`, because these functions return only numbers or `NaN`. Also this will make sure that if you have a numeric string then it is also treated like a number.

Comment: I did not try all browsers (and maybe browsers have changed the way they handle isNaN since your answer), but what you say is not correct in Chrome 34: http://jsfiddle.net/ss5ja/

Comment: @GôTô - Interesting. I don't know whether I made a mistake 4 years ago, or things have indeed changed. Still, the behavior of the function can be odd in some other edge cases: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN.

Comment: Yeah... Not sure what is considered the best way to replace `isNaN` but it does not seem trustworthy indeed!

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = 10;
if (isNaN(x) || (x < 5) || (x > 15)) {
    alert('not allowed')
}
else
{
    callMe();
}
```